# D3.js Draw Circle between dash

Tags: svg, d3.js

tried trying to draw circle and dash in one path

```
like this : ..--..--..--..--..--..--..
```

2 dot and 2 dashes and how can handle it with function

like this :

```
function Draw_Dash_And_Circle(x1,y1,x2,y2){
draw dash and circle on the single line
}
```

i type this code and work well
but need logical code for tracing dots location

```
<!-- Two dash Two Dot -->
var x1,x2,y1,y2,cx1,cy1,cx2,cy2;
x1 = 0;
x2 = 1;
y1 = 90;
y2 = 90;
for (let i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
 svg.append('line')
.style("stroke", "black")
.style("stroke-width", 0.5)
.attr("x1", x1)
.attr("y1", y1)
.attr("x2", x2)
.attr("y2", y2); 
x1 += 2;
x2 += 2;
 svg.append('line')
.style("stroke", "black")
.style("stroke-width", 0.5)
.attr("x1", x1)
.attr("y1", y1)
.attr("x2", x2)
.attr("y2", y2); 
cx1 = x2 + 3;
 svg.append('circle')
.attr("cx",cx1)
.attr("r",0.5)
.attr("cy",y2);
cx2 = cx1 + 2;
svg.append('circle')
.attr("cx",cx2 )
.attr("r",0.5)
.attr("cy",y2);
 x2 = cx2 + 2;
 x1 = cx2 + 3;
}
```

please help me

thanks.

Answer (score 1):

While you could append circles and lines or other elements along a path or line's route, it is probably easier to append two paths/lines and use stroke dash arrays and stroke line caps to style the lines into a collection of circles and/or squares/rectangles:

Eg for lines:

```
 selection.append("line")
    .attr("x1", d=>d.x1)
    .attr("x2", d=>d.x2)
    .attr("y1", d=>d.y1)
    .attr("y2", d=>d.y2)
    .attr("stroke","black")
    .attr("stroke-width", 12)
    .attr("stroke-dasharray", "0 16 0 48")
    .attr("stroke-linecap","round");

  selection.append("line")
    .attr("x1", d=>d.x1)
    .attr("x2", d=>d.x2)
    .attr("y1", d=>d.y1)
    .attr("y2", d=>d.y2)
    .attr("stroke","black")
    .attr("stroke-width", 12)
    .attr("stroke-dasharray", "0 16 0 48")
    .attr("stroke-dashoffset", "32" )
    .attr("stroke-linecap","square")
```

Or for paths:

```
 var line = d3.line()
    .curve(d3.curveBasis);
  
 selection.append("path")
    .attr("d",line)
    .attr("stroke","black")
    .attr("stroke-width", 12)
    .attr("stroke-dasharray", "0 16 0 48")
    .attr("stroke-linecap","round")
    .style("fill","none")

  selection.append("path")
    .attr("d",line)
    .attr("stroke","black")
    .attr("stroke-width", 12)
    .attr("stroke-dasharray", "0 16 0 48")
    .attr("stroke-dashoffset", "32" )
    .attr("stroke-linecap","square")
    .style("fill","none")
```

Which gives something like:

[image]

```js
var svg = d3.select("svg");

var linedata = [
  {x1: 100, y1: 50, x2: 300, y2: 50},
  {x1: 100, y1: 250, x2: 300, y2: 250}
]

svg.selectAll("g")
  .data(linedata)
  .join("g")
  .call(line);


function line(selection) {

 selection.append("line")
    .attr("x1", d=>d.x1)
    .attr("x2", d=>d.x2)
    .attr("y1", d=>d.y1)
    .attr("y2", d=>d.y2)
    .attr("stroke","black")
    .attr("stroke-width", 12)
    .attr("stroke-dasharray", "0 16 0 48")
    .attr("stroke-linecap","round");

  selection.append("line")
    .attr("x1", d=>d.x1)
    .attr("x2", d=>d.x2)
    .attr("y1", d=>d.y1)
    .attr("y2", d=>d.y2)
    .attr("stroke","black")
    .attr("stroke-width", 12)
    .attr("stroke-dasharray", "0 16 0 48")
    .attr("stroke-dashoffset", "32" )
    .attr("stroke-linecap","square")

}

var pathdata = [
   [50,100],
   [150,200],
   [250,100],
   [350,200]
]

svg.append("g")
  .datum(pathdata)
  .call(path);

function path(selection) {
  
 var line = d3.line()
    .curve(d3.curveBasis);
  
 selection.append("path")
    .attr("d",line)
    .attr("stroke","black")
    .attr("stroke-width", 12)
    .attr("stroke-dasharray", "0 16 0 48")
    .attr("stroke-linecap","round")
    .style("fill","none")

  selection.append("path")
    .attr("d",line)
    .attr("stroke","black")
    .attr("stroke-width", 12)
    .attr("stroke-dasharray", "0 16 0 48")
    .attr("stroke-dashoffset", "32" )
    .attr("stroke-linecap","square")
    .style("fill","none")

}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/7.0.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<svg width= "500" height="300"></svg>
```

Also easy to animate:

```js
var svg = d3.select("svg");

var linedata = [
  {x1: 100, y1: 50, x2: 300, y2: 50},
  {x1: 100, y1: 250, x2: 300, y2: 250}
]

svg.selectAll("g")
  .data(linedata)
  .join("g")
  .call(line);


function line(selection) {

 selection.append("line")
    .attr("x1", d=>d.x1)
    .attr("x2", d=>d.x2)
    .attr("y1", d=>d.y1)
    .attr("y2", d=>d.y2)
    .attr("stroke","black")
    .attr("stroke-width", 12)
    .attr("stroke-dasharray", "0 16 0 48")
    .attr("stroke-linecap","round")
    .transition()
    .attr("stroke-dashoffset",1000)
    .duration(20000)

  selection.append("line")
    .attr("x1", d=>d.x1)
    .attr("x2", d=>d.x2)
    .attr("y1", d=>d.y1)
    .attr("y2", d=>d.y2)
    .attr("stroke","black")
    .attr("stroke-width", 12)
    .attr("stroke-dasharray", "0 16 0 48")
    .attr("stroke-dashoffset", "32" )
    .attr("stroke-linecap","square")
    .transition()
    .attr("stroke-dashoffset",1032)
    .duration(20000)
}

var pathdata = [
   [50,100],
   [150,200],
   [250,100],
   [350,200]
]

svg.append("g")
  .datum(pathdata)
  .call(path);

function path(selection) {
  
 var line = d3.line()
    .curve(d3.curveBasis);
  
 selection.append("path")
    .attr("d",line)
    .attr("stroke","black")
    .attr("stroke-width", 12)
    .attr("stroke-dasharray", "0 16 0 48")
    .attr("stroke-linecap","round")
    .style("fill","none")
    .transition()
    .attr("stroke-dashoffset",1000)
    .duration(20000)       

  selection.append("path")
    .attr("d",line)
    .attr("stroke","black")
    .attr("stroke-width", 12)
    .attr("stroke-dasharray", "0 16 0 48")
    .attr("stroke-dashoffset", "32" )
    .attr("stroke-linecap","square")
    .style("fill","none")
    .transition()
    .attr("stroke-dashoffset",1032)
    .duration(20000)    

}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/7.0.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<svg width= "500" height="300"></svg>
```